# How to make an if statement if your pointer is getting garbage

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

Hi everyone I have a problem taking care of a malfunction, I'm building a dynamic linked list which connects structures with *next and *previous, 
now if the structures are unable to connect (long story) I need to print "the way does not exist" now I've made an if statement

```
    temp = point_start; // point_start is the head of the list
condition = 2;
for(i=0;i<gagnum;i++) //gagnum is the number of structures
{ 
    temp=point_start->previous; // previous is the pointer of the previous structure. 

    if (temp != 0xcdcdcdcd) // ------> is this legal?
        condition = 1;
    else
    {
        printf("no route found ") 
        condition = 2;
        break;
    }

}
```

I have an if statement which says "if (temp != 0xcdcdcdcd)" so when it gets garbage I put out the message and stop the program, is this legal to use? is there a better way to do this? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You will have to provide more context, i.e. make a [mcve]. Add the meaning of 0xcdcdcdcd, please. It is definitly no officially defined constant for "garbage"... ;-)

Comment: Its really hard to explain because the complete job is like 400 lines long and has nothing to do with this issue, I just want to make a proper if statement for if the linked list was unable to connect itself the program stops, meaning if temp->previous is garbage program stops.

Comment: Also your logic appears to be flawed. The `break` statement will exit the `for()` loop the first time you encounter a value of `temp` that doesn't equal your magic constant.

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want to do, when it breaks out of the loop I use the condition=2 further in the code for that exact problem

Comment: just please help me make a proper if statement, that's my problem

Comment: you cannot test for garbage. Design your code so this never happens instead.

Comment: I think the term "garbage" is used with different meanings by the participants of the discussion. I recommend to define the meaning. @alexdr3x, please start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `0xcdcdcdcd`, you should be using `0x0` to indicate a NULL pointer.

Here's a function which does what I think you're trying to do:

```
// checks to see if the given list is the "first" structure
bool is_first_structure(void* head)
{
    return head->previous != NULL;
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
if(!is_first_structure(head))
{
    printf("no route found");
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer but can you explain to me more about the first part of your comment? (bool) I seem to have trouble understanding what it does.

Comment: @alexdr3x `bool` is a type which is either `true` (1) or `false` (0).

Comment: oh I see, Its a college project and we are not allowed to us this * since we did not learn this * is there another way?

Comment: @alexdr3x You can use `int` instead.

Comment: Oh awesome, but again excuse me for my ignorance, how does the first part work , what do I input in there?

Comment: That is a function definition, which you write near the top of your file, underneath the `#include`s. You can use it later on in your code, like I did in the second code snippet.

Comment: Yes I understood that part, I just don't get it how does that function knows if my pointer is garbage or not?

Comment: There's no way to *actually* tell if something is garbage or not. The conventional way people deal with this is by making sure unused pointers are set to `NULL`. If you make sure your pointers are initialized to `NULL` and set to `NULL` after you delete the memory, this should work.

Comment: Mateen Ulhaq I love you man! I just set all my pointers to null and then I tested if its null or not THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

Hi the answer to the problem is just to NULL all your pointers when you're building the linked list.  then check if the pointer is NULL instead of garbage, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values) writes for 0xcdcdcdcd

> Used by Microsoft's C/C++ debug malloc() function to mark uninitialized heap memory, usually returned from HeapAlloc()

So I guess you malloc a node and not initializing the pointers.